# Avoiding circular depenency between Arena and Portal

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to resolve this ciruclar dependency while preferebly keeping both objects immutable.

```
public class Arena {

    private final Portal portal;

    Arena(Portal portal) {
        this.portal = portal;
    }

    void close() {
        portal.close();
    }

    void start() {

    }
}

public class Portal {

    private final Arena arena;

    Portal(Arena arena) {
        this.arena = arena;
    }

    void close() {

    }

    void start() {
        arena.start();
    }

}
```

Basically, I need portal to be able to activate itself, and start the arena. Opposite, I need Arena to reset & close itself, and the portal. I found a solution by having two HashMap's <Arena, Portal> and <Portal, Arena>, however I want to figure out if it's a better way to solve this for learning and progression.

The classes are made more simple in here, as in reality they have more variables and identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not a wrapper class for both `Arena` and `Portal`:

```
public class PortalArena {

    private final Portal portal;

    private final Arena arena;

    PortalArena(Portal portal, Arena arena) {
        this.portal = portal;
        this.arena = arena;
    }
    
    void startPortal() {
        portal.start();
        arena.start();
        // Rest of the logic here
    }

    void closeArena() {
        arena.close();
        portal.close();
        // Rest of the logic here
    }
 
    //....

}
```

Comment: Would this not just be an additional layer to the circular dependency? Or how would it be stored. Inside the Portal and Arena class themselves or?

Comment: This is instead of a `Portal` class with an `Arena` field, and an `Arena` class with a `Portal` field. The relation between both instances is in the wrapper class, so you avoid any circular reference.

Comment: Omg, this makes so much more sense. They already share name either way :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. This is similar to what you were doing with the `HashMap`, using a `Map.Entry` as a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dependency inversion, so Portal will not depend on Arena

```
interface Startable{
  void start();
}

class Arena extends Startable{...}
```

and then:

```
class Portal{
  private final Startable arena;
  ...
}
```

though looking at Arena and Portal methods, it looks like those are not immutable

Comment: How would this work when closing the Arena and Portal?

Comment: @user_020599 the same as in your sample code. Arena closes portal